# htaccess Replace spaces and dots with a dash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok I've got my htaccess code to work up to a point... Now I'm stuck.

Here is the original URL:

> example.com/search/store_info.php?store=113&dentist=Dr.%20John%20Doe

**What I'm trying to achieve is a clean URL** with no dots / periods or spaces  (%20) like this:

> example.com/search/113/dr-john-doe

However, with the htaccess code I'm currently using I get this result:

> example.com/search/113/dr.

The doctors name is pulled from a database and it has a dot (.) behind every "dr" so this is where the process stops in a sense. I'm guessing because of the dot?

Here is the htaccess code that I have:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /search/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /store_info\.php\?store=([a-z0-9]+)&dentist=  ([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ store_info.php?store=$1&dentist=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Wrong way of going about it. Your web pages should be generated with ONLY clean urls in them in the first place, and then you convert them back to "ugly" ones for internal usage.

Comment: @MarcB i'm trying to generate clean URLs if I didn't use the htaccess code it would have looked like `example.com/search/store_info.php?store=113&dentist=Dr.%20John%20Doe`  but the htaccess code I provided cuts off the full name of the dentist at the dot

Comment: @anubhava the code works on my end when I push it live... however it shows the URL as `example.com/search/113/dr.` and not the full doctors name.

Comment: Are you sure you have a space after `dentist=` as shown?

Comment: @anubhava when I add the space after `dentist=` it throws an error however, if there is no space then the URL works but it shows only `example.com/search/113/dr.` and not this `example.com/search/113/dr-john-doe`  you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /search/

# redirect internal URL to pretty URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /store_info\.php\?store=([a-z0-9]+)&dentist=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [L,NE,R=301]

# skip all files and directories from rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# recursive rule to repeatedly convert DOT or space to hyphen
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([^\s.]*)[.\s]+(.*)$ $1/$2-$3 [NC,DPI,E=DONE:1]

# after all the hyphen conversion is done do a redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:DONE} =1
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/([^\s.]+)$ $1/$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# internally rewrite pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ store_info.php?store=$1&dentist=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Ahhhh so close! this code works to an extent... it works because, it grabs the whole name however, is it possible to make the doctors name appear with dashes in-between the name? Such as: `dr-john-doe` and **not** like this `drjohndoe` the dashes ultimately replace the "%20" that is usually in the URL

Comment: Ok the URL works it shows up the proper way such as: `dr-john-doe` But, now the page is broke... no css or images are showing up and I used <base href="/"> as mentioned in one of your other answers from a previous question

Comment: Ok I tried the base code you provided and I get the same thing...  nothing showing up.  The original code worked and allowed all them images and CSS to work even when I used `<base href="/">` and yes I cleared cache and tried it in a private browser window.

Comment: Yes it was provided in your code up above... I copied all that code and implemented it into my htaccess file. the code you provided is inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` `</IfModule>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120531/discussion-between-anubhava-and-antivinegar).